# Elastic Search doesn't respect size when using aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elastic Search so please forgive me if the answer is obvious.

I have modified a query to use aggs to show 'distinct' results. However, after adding the aggs the `size` doesn't seem to work anymore - it always returns 10 results no matter what I set size to.

Would anyone know how I could use both aggs and size together?

My query is:

```
{
    "size": "15",
    "from": "0",
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "filter": [
          {
            "term": {
              "category": "Cars"
            }
          },
          {
            "term": {
              "location": "Sydney"
            }
          },
          {
            "term": {
              "status": true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
   "sort": [
      {
        "_score": "desc"
      },
      {
        "brand": "asc"
      }
    ],
    "aggs": {
        "brand": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "brand",
                "order": {
                    "price": "asc"
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "brand": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "size": 1,
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "price": {
                                    "order": "asc"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "price": {
                    "min": {
                        "field": "price"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: You have used nested aggregation in this, and you have set size of only inner aggregation and not the outer aggreagtion. Is it that you are always getting outer aggregation result as 10 because default is 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size parameter you have mentioned before the query, is used to set the size for the query hits, and will not affect the aggregations bucket size.
Use the size parameter inside the parent aggregation just like you have mentioned in the sub-aggregation as "size":1
The modified query to get top 10 aggs is :

```
{
    "size": "15",
    "from": "0",
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "filter": [
          {
            "term": {
              "category": "Cars"
            }
          },
          {
            "term": {
              "location": "Sydney"
            }
          },
          {
            "term": {
              "status": true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
   "sort": [
      {
        "_score": "desc"
      },
      {
        "brand": "asc"
      }
    ],
    "aggs": {
        "brand": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "brand",
                "size": 10, 
                "order": {
                    "price": "asc"
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "brand": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "size": 1,
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "price": {
                                    "order": "asc"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "price": {
                    "min": {
                        "field": "price"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks I got it working based off your answer but needed to change the last 'size' parameter to just be 1 to avoid duplicates. I have edited your answer.